# Fix broken Ubuntu operating system

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lenovo

I'm new to the forum and this is my first question.
I need help fixing the Ubuntu installation. I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 320-15IKB with Windows preinstalled. I installed Ubuntu 20.10 in dual boot. Three days ago the system broke. It was sluggish and I tried to clean up some disk space. In doing so I think I deleted the kernel files using some script that I found on the web.

If I boot up the system normally, it does not even boot Windows and doesn't have any grub2 start-up options.
In the meantime, I created a live USB with Boot-Repair and booted from there. After Boot-Repair executed, it produced the [following URL](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MYSMcT6Vg5/).

I booted the live session again and it generated a new URL (link updated). I will paste the contents for the community.

If I start GParted in the live session, the partitions from the laptop's HDD are not visible (GParted does not read the 2T HDD?).

```
boot-repair-4ppa125                                              [20210126_1315]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 16392 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 20200604, bionic, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0004,2003,2001,2002
Boot0000* Linpus lite   HD(1,MBR,0x851d18a3,0x800,0x78b800)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,28235dfd-a1b5-4667-ba74-2abbb89f5e40,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (8C-16-45-95-38-E3)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(8c16459538e3,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0003* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (8C-16-45-95-38-E3)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(8c16459538e3,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,28235dfd-a1b5-4667-ba74-2abbb89f5e40,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0005* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (8C-16-45-95-38-E3)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(8c16459538e3,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0006* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (8C-16-45-95-38-E3)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(8c16459538e3,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0007* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (8C-16-45-95-38-E3)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(8c16459538e3,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0008* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (8C-16-45-95-38-E3)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(8c16459538e3,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0009* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,28235dfd-a1b5-4667-ba74-2abbb89f5e40,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...m................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________


Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________


fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4051697664 bytes, 7913472 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x851d18a3
      Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 7913471 7911424  3.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Disk zram0: 987.2 MiB, 1035186176 bytes, 252731 sectors
Disk zram1: 987.2 MiB, 1035186176 bytes, 252731 sectors
Disk zram2: 987.2 MiB, 1035186176 bytes, 252731 sectors
Disk zram3: 987.2 MiB, 1035186176 bytes, 252731 sectors
Disk zram4: 987.2 MiB, 1035186176 bytes, 252731 sectors
Disk zram5: 987.2 MiB, 1035186176 bytes, 252731 sectors
Disk zram6: 987.2 MiB, 1035186176 bytes, 252731 sectors
Disk zram7: 987.2 MiB, 1035186176 bytes, 252731 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sdb:4052MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Sony Storage Media:;
1:1049kB:4052MB:4051MB:fat32::boot, lba;
zram5:1035MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1035MB:1035MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram3:1035MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1035MB:1035MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram1:1035MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1035MB:1035MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram6:1035MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1035MB:1035MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram4:1035MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1035MB:1035MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram2:1035MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1035MB:1035MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram0:1035MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1035MB:1035MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram7:1035MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:1035MB:1035MB:linux-swap(v1)::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sdb                                                                                                   
â””â”€sdb1 vfat     388C-489C                            851d18a3-01                          BOOT-REPAIR 
zram0                                                                                                 
zram1                                                                                                 
zram2                                                                                                 
zram3                                                                                                 
zram4                                                                                                 
zram5                                                                                                 
zram6                                                                                                 
zram7                                                                                                 

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

      Avail Use% Mounted on
sdb1    2.9G  23% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sdb1   ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Boot-Repair-Disk session
Boot-Repair-Disk session (failsafe)

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1


========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive ==========

sda 

=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[74510]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 4495: /bin/bash

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
```

It turns out that the hdd git broken, so it was not readable any more. Took it to a data recovery company and recovered some of the data.

Comment: Your paste link is 404-ing. Can you try again?

Comment: Hi Matigo! Thank you for answering. I've update the question and link within

Comment: I don't see an install of Ubuntu anywhere on that system's output. Whatever you did, seems like you were thorough.

Comment: I concur with 535733, and the `0 OS detected` is pretty ominous. Looks like you've wiped the entire drive of data.

Comment: It is seeing flash drive  as sdb, so thinks there is a sda, but  cannot read it at all. Does UEFI/BIOS show drive correctly? Do any other tools show drive at all? Try Disks, gparted, testdisk?

Comment: As @oldref stated, the flash is seen as sdb, so it knows that there is another primary drive. gparted from the live session does not sees the drive and not even Disks. For the BIOS, I should check. Boot Repair hoewer, when is starting it test some partitions from sda5 to sda7, showing errors. After that (I think it finds sda8) and boots up.